# Visual Studio Import issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, intellisense, importerror

I have created spring boot project in Visual Studio Code.

1. Intellisense is not giving any suggestion
2. VS code unable to suggest import  [please view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yapf.png)
3. unnecessary error in the default spring boot code
   [please view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEuwo.png)

Please help me out. I have wasted my hold day just to make this work. Im using Visual Studio Code on Mac OS.

I have also tried the Command Palette--> Java Clean path.
Added java.home path in VS Code settings.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code IntelliSense features are powered by a language service, and there's AI-assisted IntelliSense called [Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode) which you can install from extension marketplace. When you find IntelliSense has stopped working, the language service may not be running. Try reinstalling the `java extension pack` and restarting VS Code and this should solve the issue.